# Angular form control last observable change

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, rxjs, angular-observable

I am building an autocomplete function that is querying a backend for suggestions and would like to only get the last query that was made given a certain delay while the user is typing in an angular 5 form control. Currently my code looks like

```
 this.newVendorForm.get('address').valueChanges.pipe(delay(3000)).subscribe(
  address => {
    this.geocodeApi.getAddressSuggestions(address)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log('address suggestions');
          console.log(response);
          this.addressSuggestions = response;
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error getting address suggestion');
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
  }
);
```

This works however it makes a query for each typed in letter after 3000 ms. For example 'test' would query ['t', 'te', 'tes', 'test'] after 3000 ms. How can I just take the last change (i.e. 'test') from valueChanges after the 3000 ms delay and then do the subscribe? Thank you for you help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a mixture of `debounceTime` and `switchMap`.

```
this.newVendorForm.get('address').valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(3000),
  switchMap(address => this.geocodeApi.getAddressSuggestions(address).pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return of();
    })
  )),
  filter(Boolean),
).subscribe(response => this.addressSuggestions = response);
```

- `debounceTime` makes it so that if there are two `valueChanges` emissions within 3 seconds of each other, only the last one is used. This is different than `delay` which will emit all of the changes 3 seconds after they were made.
- `switchMap` takes an inner observable such as an http request and changes the observable stream to it -- i.e. you are now subscribed to the `getAddressSuggestions` observable stream. If something emits to `switchMap`, it will cancel the previous observable. The result of this is that if a previously made `getAddressSuggestions` call had not been completed before a new one starts, the previous one is canceled.
- The `catchError` (lettable operator version of `.catch`) is used on the `getAddressSuggestions` observable instead of the valueChanges. Otherwise, if there were an error from the API, the valueChanges observable would complete. Using `catchError` where it is allows you to handle the error without completing the valueChanges observable.
- `filter` is used to only emit responses that have values. In case there is an error, the `of()` won't be emitted. This is just one way to handle this situation though.

Finally you may want to avoid the manual `.subscribe` since you will have to `.unsubscribe`. Instead you can try to rely on the `| async` pipe in your template which will handle the subscription for you.